# how to write content of an array to hard disk

Tags: c++, c, arrays, io

i am trying to write content of a very large char array to the hard disk.
I have the following array(actually the size of it is going to be very large)
I am using the array as a bit array and after inserting a specified number of bits into it I have to copy its content to another array and write this copy into hard disk. I then empty the content of the array by assigning it 0 for further use.

```
unsigned char       bit_table_[ROWS][COLUMNS];
```

Comment: Are you using C or C++? The solutions could be very different.

Comment: @crashmstr: any is OK but I would be happy with c++

Comment: Do you have to copy it?  Why not just queue off the existing array to some thread or pool for writing to disk and create a new empty one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should open a file for writing, and then write the array to it:

```
FILE * f;
f = fopen(filepath, "wb"); // wb -write binary
if (f != NULL) 
{
    fwrite(my_arr, sizeof(my_arr), 1, f);
    fclose(f);
}
else
{
    //failed to create the file
}
```

References: [`fopen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/), [`fwrite`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fwrite/), [`fclose`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fclose/)

Answer (score 5):

Use `ofstream`, `copy` and `ostream_iterator` to leverage the power of STL:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned char bit_table_[20][40];
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 20 ; i++)
        for (int j = 0 ; j != 40 ; j++)
            bit_table_[i][j] = i^j;
    ofstream f("c:/temp/bit_table.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);
    unsigned char *buf = &bit_table_[0][0];
    copy(buf, buf+sizeof(bit_table_), ostream_iterator<unsigned char>(f, ""));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a file or a database...

a file is simple to create :

```
FILE * f;
int i,j;
f = fopen("bit_Table_File", "w");
for (i = 0 , i< ROWS , i++)
{
    for (j = 0 , j < COLUMNS , j++)
    {
        fprintf(f, "%2x", bit_table_[i][j]);
    }
}
```

to read the contents of the file, you can use `fscanf` starting from the beginning of the file :

```
FILE* f = fopen("myFile","r");
for (i = 0 , i< ROWS , i++)
    {
        for (j = 0 , j < COLUMNS , j++)
        {
            fscanf(f, "%2x", &(bit_table_[i][j]));
        }
    }
```

whereas you have to install a database (and number of tables needed) and use specific instructions to write to it.

Comment: I like this because the file is readable.  You need to close the files and I would add a delimiter, perhaps a comma, in the specification like "%2x,"

Answer (score 1):

You can Store the value of array in file

so you need

- include the fstream header file and using std::ostream;
- declare a variable of type ofstream
- open the file
- check for an open file error
- use the file
- close the file when access is no longer needed

  > ```
  > #include <fstream>
  > using std::ofstream;
  > #include <cstdlib> 
  > int main()
  > {
  >    ofstream outdata; 
  >    int i; // loop index
  >    int array[5] = {4, 3, 6, 7, 12};
  >   outdata.open("example.dat"); // opens the file
  >    if( !outdata ) { // file couldn't be opened
  >       cerr << "Error: file could not be opened" << endl;
  >       exit(1);
  >    }
  >   for (i=0; i<5; ++i)
  >       outdata << array[i] << endl;
  >    outdata.close();
  >
  >    return 0;
  > }
  > ```